# inserting string values in oracle DB shows null values in sql developer

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle11g, null

i am inserting some values in oracle tabales using jsp, it doesn't give any error/exception while inserting but when i check the record in oracle 11g using sqldeveloper it show null in all fields (it does insert a record with null values)

here my jsp doPost method code

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("username"));
    String password = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("password"));
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into libraryadmin values (?, ?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        int result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if (result == 1) {
            out.print("<h1>USER CREATED</h1>");
        } else {
            out.print("<h1>ERROR</h1>");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

that output of sqldeveloper

[image]

PS: i'm using System user of oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
String username = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("username"));
String password = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("password"));
```

use

```
String username = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("username"));
String password = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("password"));
```